# EXTJS store related error when switching tabs: ext-all-debug.js:53117 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSynchronous' of null

Tags: extjs

I have a simplified fiddle that shows the issue I'm seeing:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nbs

The application has two tabs.  Each tab contains an instance of a component made up of a tree panel and a grid.  Clicking a node in the tree populates the grid.  If you visit both tabs before clicking a node in either tree then the application behaves.  However, if you click a tree node in the first tab and thus populate the grid, then visiting the 2nd tabs throws this error:

ext-all-debug.js:53117 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSynchronous' of null

```
at constructor.loadsSynchronously (ext-all-debug.js:53117)
at constructor.createMask (ext-all-debug.js:106694)
at constructor.onRender (ext-all-debug.js:105766)
at constructor.finishRender (ext-all-debug.js:38449)
at constructor.finishRenderItems (ext-all-debug.js:76675)
at constructor.finishRender (ext-all-debug.js:76992)
at constructor.finishRenderChildren (ext-all-debug.js:79000)
at constructor.afterRender (ext-all-debug.js:37909)
at constructor.finishRender (ext-all-debug.js:38463)
at constructor.finishRenderItems (ext-all-debug.js:76675)
```

I'm building in extjs 5.1.3, but this reproduces in the latest version (6.6).  I suspect I'm missing something stupidly obvious...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...

the code that was destroying the old store was also destroying ext-store-empty - used by all empty grids etc
so I did this:

```
if (oldStore && oldStore.storeId !== 'ext-empty-store') {
                   oldStore.destroy();
               }
```

there might be a neater way, but this works.